# Global Ambient Lighting?

Tags: c++, opengl

Lets say my display function draws polygons pixel by pixel not using opengl functions, but a drawpixel function.
I call

```
   glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, global_ambient);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

where global_ambient is 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 and I have material parameters defined, that is glmaterial is never called.  Would the global ambient lighting still work as in I will not be able to see the polygon? Or would I need to define material parameters.

Comment: With a black light you will not see anything, thus it does not matter what material you choose.

Comment: @Anton: It will at least identify the points of your program at which germs are multiplying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lets say my display function draws polygons pixel by pixel not using opengl functions, but a drawpixel function.

If that's true, then the lighting state is completely irrelevant. Fixed-function OpenGL lighting is *per-vertex*. You're not sending vertices; you're sending pixel data.